# Twig template with symfony overriding block issues

Tags: symfony, twig

I got a problem is overriding template. Here is my simple code

In commonHeader.html.twig

```
{% block topsearch %}
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6 col-search">
        <form action="" method="post" class="navbar-form navbar-left form-inline nav-form-search">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12 form-search">
                <label class="sr-only" for="search">Search</label>
                <div class="input-group search-input-group col-md-12">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control input-search" id="search" placeholder="find...">
                  <div class="input-group-addon btn-search-addon">
                    <button type="submit" name="search" class="btn btn-icon-search">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit" name="search" class="btn btn-text-search">SEARCH</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

In file commonPage.html.twig I do like this:

```
{% block header %}
    {{ include('::commonHeader.html.twig') }}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

And I have many layouts that extended from commonPage.html.twig.
And on each layout, search have difference action url, so I need to override it.

Ex. in myLayout.html.twig I want to like this

```
{% extends "::commonPage.html.twig" %}
<!-- start overriding search here -->
{% block topsearch %}
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6 col-search">
        <form action="mynewactionurl" method="post" class="navbar-form navbar-left form-inline nav-form-search">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12 form-search">
                <label class="sr-only" for="search">Search</label>
                <div class="input-group search-input-group col-md-12">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control input-search" id="search" placeholder="find...">
                  <div class="input-group-addon btn-search-addon">
                    <button type="submit" name="search" class="btn btn-icon-search">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit" name="search" class="btn btn-text-search">SEARCH</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block navigationleft %}
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is that  I can't override search block in myLayout.html.twig?
Thanks for your helping!

Comment: Seem correct, what error do you have? Simple you don't see the correct action form?

Comment: I did like this but still show the old search form, not take the url that passe in action="editor/search" (just an example)

Comment: what happen if you put the block topsearch in commonpage inside header like {% block header%} {% block topsearch %}{{ include('::commonHeader.html.twig') }}{%endblock%}{%endblock%}

Comment: I worked for me, but it break my layout

Comment: So like this it overrides the topsearch?

Comment: Thanks @NawfalSerrar  Yes, if I put like you mentioned it override the top search, but I need to fix my layout because it broken.

Answer (score 1):

Then you just need to fix the layout accordingly, i think its because you need to define your blocks in the main twig , i am not sure how the twig engine renders the includes but define your block in the main twig then include what you need, do not include blocks and then trying to override them.  thats how our base.html.twig is defined. all our blocks are inside then we override them.